# Oracle express 18c Enterprise Manager login failed from firefox

Tags: linux, database, oracle

I have installed on VMware a machine with Linux Centos 8 and I'm trying to install oracle express 18c. I have completed the installation of database and if I login from the terminal with `sqlplus user=system` everything works fine, but when I try to login from the oracle enterprise manager with a firefox browser with the same account I have connection error. The message say that the *instance is inactive*. 
The status is as follows:

```
Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                21-MAR-2020 23:10:31
Uptime                    2 days 18 hr. 14 min. 3 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/localhost/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/admin/XE/xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "a1626a10a6df3284e055000000000001" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xepdb1" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

the tnsnames.ora is:

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
```

Comment: Show us the full url you use to attempt the connect to em express.

Comment: https://192.168.142.128:5500/em/login   the oracle EM page open correctly, the error happens when i try to login